# Validate values and throw an exception

Tags: java, if-statement, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to validate startIndex and endIndex, and throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException if they are invalid. I am trying to throw an exception on purpose. This code throws the exception, but stops the program. I need to handle the exception and have the program continue. I need some help with this code. Thanks in advance

```
public int findMinReadingIndex2(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        if (startIndex < 0 || endIndex < 0 || endIndex >= this.sensorReadings.size())
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds: 0 - " + (this.sensorReadings.size() - 1));
        else
            sensorReadings.get(startIndex);
            int minIndex = 0;
            startIndex = -1;
            endIndex = 18;
                for (int i = startIndex; i < sensorReadings.size(); i++) {
                    if (i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex) {
                    if (this.sensorReadings.get(minIndex).getValue() < this.sensorReadings.get(i).getValue())
                        minIndex = i;
                }
            }
            return minIndex;
        }
```

Comment: If you throw any exception, execution stops at that point. If you want to validate and continue, you can do that without writing throw. Just remove throw statement, remove else statement and write your code to handle the input in first if. That's it

Comment: The point of this exercise is to put in bad input, throw and exception, handle it with a msg, then continue

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to use a try-catch instead of an if-statement. I'm not guaranteeing it will work - but it will definitely be a step in the right direction... Something along the likes of:

```
try {
    sensorReadings.get(startIndex);
            int minIndex = 0;
            startIndex = -1;
            endIndex = 18;
                for (int i = startIndex; i < sensorReadings.size(); i++) {
                    if (i >= startIndex && i <= endIndex) {
                    if (this.sensorReadings.get(minIndex).getValue() < this.sensorReadings.get(i).getValue())
                        minIndex = i;
                }
            }
            return minIndex;
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
    handleTheExceptionSomehow(exception);
    //Program should continue just fine
}
```